# AJAXify: Force certain links to load without AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, history.js

I am using history.js to achieve page transitions on a site I am working on.

I have a couple of page types that do not work correctly with AJAXify as they require an additional javascript file and they don't have the main menu. When they are loaded, the JavaScript isn't pulled in and AJAXify tries to keep the menu. If I refresh the page these load as expected so I want to be able to load the page in the standard way. Linking back to the main areas of the site with AJAX also causes issues as it doesn't load the main navigation.

What I want to know is: is there anything like jQuery Mobile's `[data-ajax="false"]` that I can add to links where I do not want to load the URL with AJAX?

Comment: As a side note, I have tried rel="external" on the links but this did not make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ajaxify-html5.js there is:

```
// Ajaxify
$this.find('a:internal:not(.no-ajaxy)').click(function(event){
....
}
```

This applies the AJAX to every link that does not have the class "no-ajaxy" so I simply added this class to the links I did not want to link with AJAX.

Easy